# What wheel to use?

Tags: wheels, compatibility

I am currently using the remedy 7 2020 and it is a great bike for the price, however recently my rear wheel broke and I have been struggling hard to find a new compatible one. I am new to biking but it seems I have scoured the whole internet for a simple replacement part.
If anyone can help me here are the details, also it would be great if I could order from a country inside the EU,
12x148 boost
IS 6 bolts disc brakes
tires: 27.5x2.6 XR4 Team Issue

Also, some more details, the old wheel that was on there was the Line Comp 30 TLR Boost, these are out of production and not on sale anywhere I could find. Similar wheels I could not find like previously mentioned.

Comment: You may be able to get a replacement from TREK. You will have to visit a Trek dealer, who will consult Dexter and let you know availability.

Comment: This doesn’t work in the opposite direction but FWIW you could use an adapter to mount your 6 bolt rotor to a center lock wheel. The replacement doesn’t need to be 6 bolt, which may open up some options with the current parts shortage

Comment: What actually broke?  Do you really need an entire new pre built wheel?

Answer (score 2):

Specs you need to match:

- Wheel size: 27.5"
- Rim width: 30-35mm
- Disc mount: 6-Bolt
- Axle standard: 12/148mm Boost
- Freehub: Shimano (HG) (not Microspline!)

Many shops let you filter the wheels after some of these criteria.
For example (missing the rim width): [Bike24](https://www.bike24.com/cycling/parts/bike-wheels?menu=1000%2C1868%2C1928&__qf_form-filter=&pgc%5B72%5D%5B475%5D=1&pgc%5B87%5D%5B535%5D=1&pgc%5B128%5D%5B749%5D=1&pgc%5B130%5D%5B769%5D=1&pgc%5B129%5D%5B757%5D=1)